# How to evenly distributed margin with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: the picture]
I want to display the UI as the picture, and I use a loop to creat the div , so I think flex is the most convince way to do it . each row displays four elements and I want set the margin(top left right bottom) of each flex-item the same 10px. I tried justify-content:space-between / space-around. and neither of these is what I want.

```html
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  createDiv = () => {
    // return  div className="child" />
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contianer">
        {this.arr.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="child" />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
.contianer{
   /* width: calc(100%-20px); */
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: gray;
  justify-content: space-between
  /* flex:1; */
}

.child{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: calc((100% - 50px) / 4);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 5px

}
```

online demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fapbff

so it's there a way to achive what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for this. You can try this code. It is fully tested. I hope it will help you.

**CSS:**

```
.contianer {
  display: grid;
  background-color:red;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

By using grid, you can achieve this. I tested this code in your demo "https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fapbff". It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it with flex layout you can use align-item and height for vertical space.

see below css

```
 .contianer{

  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: gray;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: space-between;
  height: 230px;
  padding:10px 0 0 10px

}

.child{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: calc((100% - 40px) / 4);
  height: 100px;

}
```

but for full control about layout you can use grid layout.